# SSO equivalents to Windows AccessCheck call

Tags: winapi, single-sign-on

We have an windows app that runs as an Administrative account but we need to determine the access rights to files and directories of a particular user that is logged in to the app.

One solution we have used is to use the user name only to generate an access mask:

```
BuildTrusteeWithName(&trustee, username);
GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(pSecurityInfo->pAcl, &trustee, pAccessMask);
```

The problem with this is that it takes quite a long time on some customer sites with complex DFS setups. We believe the time is taken in looking up the user's groups etc...

So another solution we have used is to cache the user name and password to 'impersonate' the user, temporarily caching a handle to the 'impersonation' token:

```
// Here we get the handle to the 'impersonation' token
LogonUser(owner, NULL, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, pTempHandle);
DuplicateToken( *pTempHandle, DEFAULT_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL, pOwnerHandleCacheEntry->pHandle );

// This is then called for all files and directories traversed. pOwnerHandle is the handle of the 'impersonation' token obtained above.
// This means the overhead of getting the user's groups etc... is only done once.
AccessCheck(pSd, *pOwnerHandle, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, &genericMapping, &privilegeSet, &dwPrivSetSize, &fileAccessMask, &accessStatus);
```

The problem with this is if we wish to introduce Single Sign On, we don't have access to the user's password. This will leave some sites that wish to use SSO with a system that doesn't perform very well as they will need to switch back to first solution (above).

So, my questions are:

1)  Is there a way of caching the user information used to build the access rights using just the user name (in order to avoid doing lookups every time) ?
2)  Failing question 1 (above), is there an equivalent of our preferred solution within an SSO environment (for example: impersonating a user using a kerberos ticket)?

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, the SSO equivalent of LogonUser is [SSPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380493.aspx).  SSPI allows a server to authenticate a client without needing the client's password.  After successfully authenticating the client, the server will have access to a user token, but as with everything in SSPI it's complicated how to get it.  From there, you can call AccessCheck which should be very fast.

Comment: Sean, could you give me a few pointers as to where to start with SSPI. It's a huge topic, and whilst it might be the right approach, I feel your answer is a little terse for a 200 rep bonus! :)

Comment: Specifically, it looks like SSPI relies on having a security context for the user, but in a SSO context, we just have the user id. So is there a way to get a security context without having a password?

Comment: @DavidArno This is partly why I didn't give more details.  I don't understand the architecture of your program.  You say it runs as Administrator, but also say that the user logs in.  I had to assume that you have a server application and a client application (or perhaps the client application is a browser?).  In an SSO context, authentication still happens, whether it's with a password or Kerberos ticket or something else.